# DISM: Error 2 The system cannot find the file specified - during /Cleanup-Image

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, dism

I was trying to get rid of old Windows Update files by running:

`Dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /AnalyzeComponentStore`.

I am getting *Error: 2 'The system cannot find the file specified'*.

Specs: Windows 8.1.

Attached is errors shown in log:

```
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=5600 TID=12168  Error in operation: (null) (CBS HRESULT=0x80070002) - CCbsConUIHandler::Error
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=5600 TID=12140 Failed finalizing changes. - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize(hr:0x80070002)
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=5600 TID=12140 Failed processing package changes with session option CbsSessionOptionAnalyzeStore - CDISMPackageManager::AnalyzeComponentStore(hr:0x80070002)
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=5600 TID=12140 Failed to analyze component store. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ProcessCmdLine_CleanupImage(hr:0x80070002)
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=5600 TID=12140 Failed while processing command cleanup-image. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x80070002)
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=5600 TID=12140 Further logs for online package and feature related operations can be found at %WINDIR%\logs\CBS\cbs.log - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Error                 DISM   DISM.EXE: DISM Package Manager processed the command line but failed. HRESULT=80070002
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5600 TID=12140 Found the OSServices.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5600 TID=12140 Found the OSServices.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5600 TID=12140 Found the PE Provider.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5600 TID=12140 Finalizing the servicing provider(DISM Package Manager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=5600 TID=12140 Finalizing CBS core. - CDISMPackageManager::Finalize
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5600 TID=12140 Disconnecting Provider: DISM Package Manager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5600 TID=12140 Finalizing the servicing provider(MsiManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5600 TID=12140 Disconnecting Provider: MsiManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5600 TID=12140 Finalizing the servicing provider(IntlManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5600 TID=12140 Disconnecting Provider: IntlManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5600 TID=12140 Finalizing the servicing provider(IBSManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5600 TID=12140 Disconnecting Provider: IBSManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5600 TID=12140 Finalizing the servicing provider(DriverManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5600 TID=12140 Disconnecting Provider: DriverManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5600 TID=12140 Finalizing the servicing provider(DISM Unattend Manager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5600 TID=12140 Disconnecting Provider: DISM Unattend Manager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5600 TID=12140 Finalizing the servicing provider(SmiManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5600 TID=12140 Disconnecting Provider: SmiManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5600 TID=12140 Finalizing the servicing provider(AppxManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5600 TID=12140 Disconnecting Provider: AppxManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5600 TID=12140 Finalizing the servicing provider(AssocManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5600 TID=12140 Disconnecting Provider: AssocManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5600 TID=12140 Finalizing the servicing provider(GenericManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5600 TID=12140 Disconnecting Provider: GenericManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5600 TID=12140 Finalizing the servicing provider(Edition Manager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5600 TID=12140 Disconnecting Provider: Edition Manager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5600 TID=12140 Releasing the local reference to OSServices. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5600 TID=12140 Disconnecting Provider: OSServices - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5600 TID=12140 Releasing the local reference to DISMLogger.  Stop logging. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Image session has been closed. Reboot required=no.
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: 
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: <----- Ending Dism.exe session ----->
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: 
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12236 TID=6156 Found the OSServices.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12236 TID=6156 Disconnecting Provider: FolderManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-04-27 01:37:01, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12236 TID=6156 Releasing the local reference to DISMLogger.  Stop logging. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
```

Comment: copy the folder C:\Windows\logs\CBS to the desktop, zip the folder, upload (OneDrive) the zip and post a link here.